# Is cleaning of teeth necessary for healthier gums?

Tags: hygiene, dentistry

I found the [following passage](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=F-Q_xGjWBi8C&pg=PT28&lpg=PT28&vq=surprise) in *Man's Search for Meaning* by Dr Viktor Frankl

> I would like to mention a few similar surprises on how much we could
>   endure: we were unable to clean our teeth, and yet, in spite of that
>   and a severe vitamin deficiency, we had healthier gums than ever
>   before.

Is there any research that supports this claim?

Comment: What is your question, exactly?

Comment: @Flimzy I want to know whether Frankl's claim that their gums grew healthier even though they never cleaned their teeth is true. Is it backed by scientific research?

Comment: So you're asking for confirmation of an anecdote? That doesn't quite seem on topic here. Also, that's not what your title says--your title says, essentially, is it possible to make gums healthier without cleaning ones teeth, which is almost certainly true, at least in many cases.